# symbols are not displayed properly in mozilla

Tags: html, css, mozilla, symbols

I have problem with a web page where it is display some symbols wrongly only in mozilla. The page is [click here](http://www.winmansoftware.com/FAQ.htm) In this page there are so many -> symbols used. It is displayed as  ® in mozilla. So how can i make it to display properly as -> symbol in mozilla. The page has style which are created by micosoft word. I want to retain those as it is.So any css trick can i use it to do?
To get the error i am facing please go to this [page](http://www.winmansoftware.com/FAQ.htm) and search for  software ® click ‘Buy now’.

Comment: Did you test it on Chrome ? I can't see your arrow.

Comment: in chrome arrow comes. i have tested it

Comment: Well, it doesn't work for me.

Comment: which chrome version u tried?

Comment: I am not going to a website to look at code. Next time add in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use specific Microsoft extensions :

```
<span style="mso-list:Ignore">§<span style="font:7.0pt &quot;Times New Roman&quot;">&nbsp; </span></span>
```

And defining fonts in style enclosing them with `&quot;` is clearly buggy.

I don't know what MSWord tries to do but it's obviously not trying to build a standard HTML document for the World Wide Web. Is that a recent version ?

You'll have to fix the generated HTML.

Another problem is that your rendering relies on the Times New Roman font, which isn't available in non Windows computer.

Using standard HTML and encoding your document in UTF-8, you could replace those spans with [simple arrow characters](http://utf8-characters.com/arrows/).

But the better solution would be to simply forget the idea to convert a MSOffice document to HTML and to build a proper HTML document instead.

Comment: Do i have any method or trick to solve the problem other than changing full page into html?